# Date Field Format not working properly

Tags: date

I have this code

```
<div class="control-group {if error:birthdate}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="birthdate">{label:birthdate}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {if logged_out}
                <input class="span2" data-title="Help" data-placement="right" data-trigger="focus" data-content="{instructions:birthdate}" required type="date" name="birthdate" value="{if '{exp:parameters:post name="birthdate"}'}{exp:parameters:post name="birthdate"}{/if}" id="birthdate">
            {if:else}
                {birthdate}
                <input class="span2" data-title="Help" data-placement="right" data-trigger="focus" data-content="{instructions:birthdate}" disabled type="date" value="{birthdate format="%Y-%m-%d"}" id="birthdate">
            {/if}
            {if error:birthdate}
                <span class="help-inline">{error:birthdate}</span>
            {/if}
        </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that while `{birthdate}` is outputting properly, `{birthdate format="%Y-%m-%d"}` is **always** outputting `1970-01-01`.

Any idea why this is the case? I am using EE 2.5.5

UPDATE:

The actual value stored in the exp_channel_data is `503150405`. Converting this timestamp using this [site](http://www.epochconverter.com/) yielded

`GMT: Wed, 11 Dec 1985 12:00:05 GMT`

The output using `{birthdate}` yields

`1985-12-12 12:00 AM`

So I think the data is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What is output by {birthdate} without adding any formatting?

What fieldtype are you using to store {birthdate}?

If you are using a text field, do you perhaps have the formatting set to Auto or XHTML which would cause an issue with the content being converted to a date and so fall back to the default of 1970-01-01

Comment: The output is something like `1985-12-12 12:00 AM`. The fieldtype being used is Date. I am using an input tag with type="date" to display it.